# PrintWriter not appending in Java, using FileOutputStream

Tags: java, append, fileoutputstream, filewriter, printwriter

This is my method to write to a file, this method belongs to a class

```
public void write(FileOutputStream fo) throws IOException
    {
        PrintWriter out=new PrintWriter(fo);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            String formatted="%3d";
            for (int j=0;j<size;j++)
            {
                out.append(String.format(formatted,arr[i][j]));
            }
            out.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }
        out.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        out.close();
    }
```

I want to write my results into many different files, corresponding to input files read by appropriate created object, so I pass the to-be-written file as a parameter to this method

It doesn't append at all

After spending hours searching for solution of this problem, I only got results of appending using PrintWriter with a specified path of file, for example:

```
PrintWriter out=new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("output1.txt",true));
```

If I use

```
PrintWriter out=new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(fo,true));
```

I encounter error

It doesn't append when write method of my 2 instances of that object is called

```
public void writeSolution() throws IOException
    {
        fo=new FileOutputStream("output\\output1.txt",true);
        start.write(fo);
        goal.write(fo);
        fo.close();
    }
```

Please help me solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

When you close a `PrintWriter`, the `close()` method *also closes the underlying stream/writer*.

In every call to your `write` method, you open your `PrintWriter` and then you close it at the end. This means the stream is closed. Next time you open a `PrintWriter` to it, it is a closed file. You can't write to a closed file.

A `PrintWriter` does not throw exceptions when you do something like this, so it silently does nothing. And you are not calling its `checkError()` method, so you don't know that there was an error there.

What you should do is declare the `PrintWriter` as a field (so that it maintains its state between calls to `write()`, open it before you start calling the `write()` method, and close it after you finish calling the `write()` method for the last time. And remember to check errors.

Comment: But how can I pass fo as a parameter?

Comment: I did as you said and it writes nothing to my file